# Sort class instance alphabetically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have this code which works on numbers (distance) which allows me to sort by closest to farthest.  However I would like to do something similar but instead sort alphabetically.  So I need to sort self.names alphabetically essentially.  Also, I'd like to eventually sort self.names alphabetically and if you have identical names then sort those by distance.  Is this possible?

```
- (NSComparisonResult)sortByDistFromVor:(radiostations *)anObject
{

    if ([self.distFromVor doubleValue] < [anObject.distFromVor doubleValue]) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ([self.distFromVor doubleValue] > [anObject.distFromVor doubleValue]) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String implements a comparison, so the radiostations class (whose name ought to be capitalized by convention) can implement it's name comparison like this:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)sortByName:(radiostations *)anObject {

    return [self.name compare:anObject.name];
}
```

And to get a secondary sort as you described:

```
- (NSComparisonResult)sortByNameThenDistance:(radiostations *)anObject {

    NSComparisonResult result = [self sortByName:anObject];
    return (result == NSOrderedSame)? [self sortByDistFromVor:anObject] : result;
}
```

Comment: Alphabetically works great.  However, With the secondary sort, I get a "implicit conversion of 'NSComparisonResult' (aka 'int') is disallowed with ARC". and a "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion returning 'NSComparisonResult' (aka 'int') from a function with a result type 'id'

Comment: Edited the obvious compile problem (sorry bout that).  What line causes the error?

Comment: Yeah - I think it's because I multiply misspelled NSComparisonResult.  My bad.  Hard to compile on my own because I didn't want to build a radio station object.  Edited code compiles for me when i replace radio stuff with all strings.

Comment: I fixed the mispelling however I think if I understand correctly, with ARC (which is enabled) I can't use an integer which is "result" and use that as a pointer to an id type.  Since an id points to an object and not an actual number.  However I dont really know how to get around it.